# How to get feed back from threads? Java

Tags: java, concurrency

For example, I launched threads 1,2 and 3, how do I keep an eye on the state of the threads? Or how do I get return values from them?

Lets say I have a server class that has threads listen(), I would like to be able to get some values from listen() or vice versa.

```
Server -> listen().getValue().
listen() get arraylist from server.
```

Comment: what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: so you don't want state, you just need a return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called Java IPC (inter process communication) mechanisms. There are plenty. For IPC in a single JVM, you can look into java.util.concurrent package, such as [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [java.util.concurrent.Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)